# How to calculate this dependent probability (marbles without replacement)?

Tags: hypergeometric-distribution, dependent-variable, sum, birthday-paradox

I present the question in two steps:

**First**:
Let there be 100 bags. A person puts 5 marbles into 5 separate, randomly selected, bags. You are now to collect the contents of the bags, one by one. If you have collected 3 marbles, you stop. What is then the expected number of bags to open for a 50% chance of getting 3 marbles?

I suspect that this is some kind of binomial distribution, but I can’t really phrase the exact solution.

**Second**:
Let there be 99 bags, and 500 marbles of 100 different colors, so that there exists 5 marbles of each color. For each of the 100 colors, a person takes all 5 marbles of that color and puts them into 5 separate, randomly selected, bags. I.e. each bag contains on average 5.05 marbles, and no bag contains more than 1 marble of the same color.

You are now to collect the contents of the bags, one by one. If you have collected 3 marbles of *the same color*, you stop. What is then the expected number of bags to open for a 50% chance of getting 3 marbles of the same color?

This second problem feels more like the birthday problem, but with multiple birthdays.

How do I calculate these expected values?

Comment: These problems are *hypergeometric* in nature.  They don't concern "expected values" in the usual statistical sense: you appear to ask for thresholds (minimal quantities) rather than expectations.

Comment: The goal is indeed to get 3 marbles by opening as few bags as possible. The more bags you open, the higher the probability of success. What would then be a better way of phrasing the question? In the real world scenario I am dealing with, there is a "cost" to opening the bags, but I have left that out for a cleaner question. I am interested in learning what methods can be used to calculate these kind of probabilities, and then compare the probabilities of success to the cost of opening the bags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let's generalize** both questions so we don't have to solve them twice:

> Let there be $n\ge 0$ bins indexed $1,2,\ldots, n.$  Suppose there are $C\gt 0$ different colors of marbles and $0\le k\le n$ marbles of each color.  Distribute each set of $k$ marbles into $k$ distinct bins randomly.  Collect all marbles from bin $1,$ then bin $2,$ and so on until you first obtain $m\ge 0$ (and $m\le k$) of at least one color.  Let $I$ be the index of the bin you last emptied.
>
> What is the distribution of $I?$  Specifically, what is its 50th percentile?

This abstract rephrasing suggests some **useful simplifications:**

1. Each color $c$ determines a simple random sample (without replacement) of the bins.  Sorting the bin indexes, we may express this sample as the indexes $1 \le X^{(c)}_1 \lt X^{(c)}_2 \lt \cdots \lt X^{(c)}_k \le n.$
2. Therefore, $X^{(c)}_m$ (which is the $m^\text{th}$ *order statistic* of this sample) is the index at which we will have first collected $m$ marbles of color $c.$
3. Consequently, $I$ is the *minimum* over all colors of $X^{(c)}_m.$  The specifications of the problem imply these random variables are identically distributed and independent (*iid*).

**That reduces the question to two simpler subproblems.**  First (dropping the superscript $(c)$), find the distribution of $X_m.$  Second, find the distribution of the minimum of $C$ *iid* variables.

#### First subproblem

Let $1\le i\le n$ be a possible value of $X_m.$  Compute the distribution function $F_{m;\,n,k}$ of $X_m$ from its definition,

$$F_{m;\,n,k}(i) = \Pr(X_m \le i) = \Pr(\text{the sample includes at least } m \text{ bins in }\{1,2,\ldots, i\}).$$

Partitioning the event "at least $m$" into the disjoint events "exactly $m,$" "exactly $m+1,$" and so on enables us immediately to express this in terms of Binomial coefficients as

> $$F_{m;\,n,k}(i) = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}\sum_{j=m}^k \binom{i}{j}\binom{n-i}{k-j},$$

a [hypergeometric tail probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

#### Second subproblem

Let $F$ be any distribution on the integers $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}.$  The distribution of the minimum of $C$ *iid* samples $X_1, \ldots, X_C$ of $F$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
F^{(C)}(i) &= \Pr(\min(X_c)\le i) \\
&= 1 - \Pr(X_1\gt i)\Pr(X_2\gt i)\cdots\Pr(X_C\gt i) \\
&= 1 - (1 - F(i))^C.
\end{aligned}$$

#### The distribution of $I$

Applying this to the previous result shows

> $$\Pr(I \le i) = F^{(C)}_{m;\,n,k}(i) = 1 - (1 - F_{m;\,n,k}(i))^C.$$

#### Solution to the original problem

The second question asks for the smallest $i$ for which $F^{(100)}_{3;\,99,5}(i) \ge 50\%.$

**We may find that by a direct search:** the value is $11,$ *just barely:* $F^{(100)}_{3;\,99,5}(10) = 0.4963\ldots$ while $F^{(100)}_{3;\,99,5}(11) = 0.6059\ldots$ .

#### Simulation

As a check, I simulated 10,000 independent repetitions of the process described in the second question (which, because it distributes balls into bins a million times, takes a few seconds).

Here are plots of the empirical distribution of $X_3$ (in black) compared to its probability function $f$ and distribution function $F$ (in red):

[image: Figure 1]

The answer to question #2, by the way, is found by inspecting the red points in the right hand plot (showing the distribution of $X^{(C)}_m$) to find the leftmost one at a height of $0.5$ or greater.  Because the height at $10$ is almost exactly $0.5,$ it's necessary to look at its value (slightly less than $0.5$) to discover the correct answer must be $11.$

**The agreement between simulation and theory is excellent,** as confirmed by a $\chi^2$ test (df = 21, p = 0.57) as well as this "rootogram" comparing the empirical frequencies by plotting the difference in their roots against their expected square root:

[image: Figure 2]

All residuals (but one, near the left) are small and display no trend.  Repeated simulations confirm there is no systematic problem.

#### Code

This `R` code implements the formula for $F$ (efficiently) and generates the simulation and figures.  You may use it to study the first question.

```R
#
# Sample randomly from a process.
#
rcolor <- function(N, n, k, m, C=1) {
  replicate(N,
            min(replicate(C, {
              x <- sample.int(n, k)
              x[order(x)[m]]
            })))
}
#
# Compute the distribution function.
#
pcolor <- function(i, n, C, k, m) {
  i <- pmin(n-1, i+1)
  1 - exp(C * phyper(m-1, i, n-i, k, log.p=TRUE))
}
#
# Create the simulation.
#
n <- 99
m <- 3
k <- 5
C <- 100
set.seed(17)
x <- rcolor(1e4, n, k, m, C)
#
# Create figure 1.
#
y <- tabulate(x, n)
y <- y / sum(y)
p <- diff(P <- pcolor(0:n, n, C, k, m))
i <- seq(min(x), max(x)) # Limits plots to the observed values

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(i, y[i], type="h", xlab=bquote({X^{(.(C))}}[.(m)]), ylab="Relative Frequency",
     main=bquote({f^{(.(C))}}[list(.(m), .(n), .(k))]))
points(i, p[i-1], col="Red", cex=1)

plot(ecdf(x), xlab=bquote({X^{(.(C))}}[.(m)]), ylab="Relative Frequency",
     main=bquote({F^{(.(C))}}[list(.(m), .(n), .(k))]))
points(i, P[i], col="Red", cex=1.25)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#
# Create figure 2.
#
x.tot <- tabulate(x, max(i))[i]
P[max(i)] <- 1
prob <- diff(P[c(min(i)-1, i)])  # The probability function `f`.
plot(sqrt(prob * length(x)), sqrt(x.tot) - sqrt(prob * length(x)), type="h",
     main="Rootogram",
     ylab="Residual", xlab=expression(sqrt(expected * phantom(0) * frequency)))
abline(h=0, col="Gray", lwd=1)
#
# Formally compare the simulation to the theory.
# (Ignore the warning: the few small-expectation bins don't harm the chi-squared
# approximation used to compute the p-value.)
#
chisq.test(x.tot, p=prob)
```